# Accessing Properties in object using bracket notation

Tags: javascript

I'm using an ajax call through javascript and returning json.

[image]

I'm accessing the data using bracket notation because the object name had spaces, so I couldn't use dot notation.

This is the success function of my ajax call(not putting in the whole ajax call because of the API key).

```
success: function(data){
     console.log(data); 
     console.log(data['Time Series (1min)']);
},
```

I want the last property in the long list of properties in the "Time Series (1min)" object. I can't call it by key/property name as every minute, the property name changes (the data is minute-by-minute). I haven't found anything so far to help me online. I've tried .last() but dot notation and brackets don't seem to jive. Any ideas?

Comment: What about `data[data.length-1]`?  or is it an Object?

Comment: you can clearly see in the screenshot that it is not an array

Comment: Grabbing the "last property" does not guarantee that it is in order, as object properties are not indexed. If you do not care about that, `var last = myObj[Object.keys(myObj)[Object.keys(myObj).length -1]];` will grab you the last item

Comment: `var last = myObj[Object.keys(myObj)[Object.keys(myObj).length - 1]];` (you need -1)

Comment: @zevee Good catch - edited.

Comment: @Bergi it's not an array.

Comment: @zero298 Oops, I didn't look at the screenshot carefully enough and OP talked about "last element" so I assumed it was an array…

Answer (score 3):

Once you got the data:

```
const series = data['Time Series (1min)'];
```

Just take all the keys and get the one with the highest timestamp:

```
const last = Object.keys(series).reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);
```

Now that weve got the highest key, its easy:

```
console.log(series[last]);
```

All that is necessary cause object key order is not guaranteed, so you may switch over to using an array or a Map.

Comment: Tried this and returned an error...script.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (script.js:32)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @J.G.Sable It's `Object.keys` not `Function.keys`?

Comment: @JonasW. You can drop the `new Date` call, ISO-formatted dates can be compared as strings directly.

Comment: I put it after the initial console log of the entire data response. I updated the code in the original post to reflect the "answer" code that I returned an error on.

Comment: @j.g.sable that problem is not related to my code. Try logging `console.log(series)` and see what you get. And please dont change your question that confuses further readers...

Comment: With this code: const series = data['Time Series (1min)'];
                console.log(series); it returns invalid API call and undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you simply want to get value of the last property of the object. (Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key/31102605#31102605) topic, object properties are sorted)

What about simpler:

```
data[Object.keys(data).pop()]
```

//Edit:

First of all you want to get "Time Series" property (which changes minute by minute), so maybe you want something like this:

```
data[Object.keys(data).find(key => key.match(/Time Series \(\d+min\)/))]
```

This will get value of time zone property in your scheme (object with dates). And - as I see - data that you receive is sorted by datetime, you can get object you are interested in by running code I've written in not edited post.

Comment: I think the main problem is that key order is not always guaranteed.  This will give you the last enumerated key of an object, but not necessarily the last timestep.  You'll have to iterate all keys if you want to do that.